# timestamp in hive reading from csv created by spark coming as null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

So I have input data coming like this:

```
HEADER_A|HEADER_B|HEADER_C|HEADER_D
2018-09-28 22:12:09.0461760|first|last|123
2018-09-28 22:14:11.0123550|first|second|124
```

I then read this into a dataframe, and save it as a temporary view named `temp_view`.  Everything is read in as a string.

I will then query this temp_view:

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("""
    SELECT
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as ETL_RunDate,
    HEADER_A as timestamp,
    HEADER_B as string,
    HEADER_c as string,
    HEADER_D as string
    FROM temp_view
""")
```

And then write that dataframe to a file.  This file with then look like

```
2018-10-23 05:32:49|2018-09-28T22:12:09.046Z|first|last|123
2018-10-23 05:32:49|2018-09-28T22:14:11.123Z|first|second|124
```

If I then use this data as the data for a hive table with schema:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `testdb.testtable`(
  `runts` timestamp COMMENT '',
  `header_a` timestamp COMMENT '',
  `header_b` string COMMENT '',
  `header_c` string COMMENT '',
  `header_d` string COMMENT '')
```

And query this table -

```
select * from testdb.testtable;
```

`header_a` is coming as null when it should be coming as the underlying data is there.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Hey, you need specify `SERDEPROPERTIES` Can you try `ALTER TABLE temp_view SET SERDEPROPERTIES ("timestamp.formats"= "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS")`. Then, query the df.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the timestamp format in your output file `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX` is different from the default Hive timestamp format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]`.

You have two options:

- Write out the file using the default format. You would have to update your write to something like `df.write.format("csv").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSS")`
- Update the SERDEPROPERTIES of the table to read the format – `ALTER TABLE testtable SET SERDEPROPERTIES ("timestamp.formats"= "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")`